# What is this creature that increases in strength as its allies die?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, product-identification

I remember some years ago coming across a creature in 3.5e that works in groups and as each individual of the group is slain the surviving creatures increase in strength. Can anyone give me the name/sourcebook if you know what I'm referring to?

I believe this was an official sourcebook, one of the monster manuals perhaps but I'm wondering if it wasn't part of a setting or in something that expands on classes (e.g. Psionics etc) sorry I don't have anything more specific, this is the reason I'm having trouble finding it again.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Good first question, just a heads-up: System identification is covered by the system tag [tag:dnd-3.5e] (which is also shown in the window title) and the question text, which is why I rolled back your title edit.

Comment: Any chance you could narrow this a *little* more? Was this a Wizards of the Coast monster from, like, a *Monster Manual* or something, or was it third party? (There are *a lot* of third party *D&D 3.X* monster resources.) Maybe a description of the accompanying illustration?

Comment: Thank you for the tips/edits.  While I am pretty confident it was an official WotC book I can't remember in what vein (class supplement or in one of the extended monster manuals)

Comment: I also have a vague recollection of such a monster; I might guess some sort of undead or divine guard. Could it be possible that they just shared a life pool among themselves?

Comment: I think there was some kind of build up in stats and I think they gave stats for 2 sizes of groups.  It's bugging me because I was hoping to use it in an upcoming adventure.  May just jerry rig something off an orc template or something like that.

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like the Huntsmen in Prydain, but I'm not aware of a d20 Prydain book. (Would be *awesome* though.)

Answer (score 9):

**Arcadian Avengers, in Monster Manual V**

The very first entry in the book, Arcadian Avengers have an ability that increases their attack and damage each time they witness an ally fall in battle. They are also lawful-aligned outsiders who can set their rolls to a fixed value up to three times per day, as well as generally advancing by class level (typically crusader, as found in *Tome of Battle*). Their entry contains notes on their ecology, as well as suggestions for adapting them to *Forgotten Realms* and *Eberron*.

**Also, Any Character Using *Consumptive Field* or *Greater Consumptive Field***

These spells, found in *Libris Mortis*, offer the caster benefits whenever any creature in the spell's area dies.

Comment: Well, one ally anyways. It's a morale bonus.